# how to change the MySQL data directory ( xampp ) win 7

Tags: mysql

I want to change the directory for MySQL in win7 to be in my dropbox folder, so i can sync up my 2 machines for developing sites.. my laptop and my desktop.  is there a config file to point mysql to a new directory.

Comment: I don't think you should do this - Dropbox will not be able to merge the changes to the mysql data files if both machines are adding/updating records.

If this is just for development and not live, do they really need to  share exactly the same data? You could just dump the DB and share that?

Comment: umm this is not live.. its just development..  I live in asia, on a tropical island.. and well i want to be able to just grab my laptop and go to the beach for a few days..  and my laptop already be up to date with the files i have been working on.  basically syncing the 2 machines up..  they both would not be adding in data at the same time.. so not sure why this would be a problem